# Estimating population average models in lmer or geepack

Tags: r, stata, generalized-estimating-equations, lme4-nlme

I would like to know how to estimate a population average model of a hierarchical logistic regression using `R` package `geepack`.

The `Stata` code is:

```
xtlogit dep ind1 ind2 ind3, i(ind4) pa
```

I would like to reproduce this in `R` using `geepack` or any other method.

Comment: @ Daniel: Your original question was "Estimating population average models in lmer". You changed it to "Estimating population average models in lmer or geepack". However, you did not modify the body of your question, i.e., you do not give any details of your problem with `geepack`. Also, please read the [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq), especially ["How do I ask questions here?"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) (please vote up helpful answers and accept answers).

Comment: @ Daniel: If you accept my answer, then you show other people that I answered your question, which is not true because I do not explain how `geepack` works. I appreciate your vote up but you better "unaccept" my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I am by no means an expert in this field but as far as I know you cannot estimate a population average model with R's lme4 package. If I am right then "population average models" use a "generalized estimating equation" (GEE) approach, see, e.g., [To GEE or Not to GEE: Comparing Population Average and Mixed Models for Estimating the Associations Between Neighborhood Risk Factors and Health](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20220526).

You might want to search for R packages that can fit generalized estimating equations (GEE), for example the package [geepack](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v15/i02/paper) or [gee](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gee/index.html).